# Crosstab totals Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I'm using Crystal Reports 10,

I need that Total Column splits in each year I have, 2012, 2013 instead of sumarizing everything in just one column, pls, any advice should be helpful...

this is what I have:

```
              Week1             Week2             Week3            Week4        Total
           2012   2013      2012   2013       2012   2013       2012   2013 
Meta1      96,900  33,350   96,900  55,584    96,900  55,584    96,900  77,818    609,936
```

This is what I need:

```
        Week1             Week2             Week3            Week4          Total
       2012   2013       2012   2013      2012   2013      2012   2013     2012   2013 
Meta1 96,900  33,350  96,900  55,584    96,900  55,584   96,900  77,818  387,600  222,336
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the total function in a cross tab grid will not be capable of separating your totals by year.

If you are using a stored procedure then you will have to do the math and select out the totals within your SQL, then simply display it like the other columns you have. This means you will not need the cross tab to create any totals for you automatically so you can turn them off by right clicking your cross tab grid and selecting "Cross-Tab Expert" then go into the "Customize Style" tab and uncheck the boxes that display totals.

If you are NOT using a stored procedure then it's still doable in Crystal Reports.  If you need a crystal only solution let me know but you've probably already figured this out by now since my response is over a year later.  Hopefully this help someone.